# Настройка Redis для Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redis

Установил я redis на ВПС на Ubuntu20.
На WordPress поставил W3 Total Cache и проходя первичную настройку вижу местами странное..

[image]

[image]

Вроде как без редиса будет быстрее.. Хотя включив кеширование объектов кол-во запросов ожидаемо уменьшилось и время загрузки сократилось.

На других серверах аналогичные непонятки (скрины кликабельны)

[image] [image]

При этом  я бы не сказал, что тут диски особо быстрые. Скорее наоборот.

Помогите разобраться с редисом, пожалуйста. Его как-то нужно настраивать для работы с ВП или что где надо сделать?

Comment: Я не использую Total Cache. В Redis кеширую только объекты. Для этого устанавливаю плагин от Till Kruss: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/. Существенно ускоряет загрузку.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Так и W3TC тоже ускоряет :) Только он, в отличи от простого, более функциональный, гибкий и  информативный. Но тут меня больше интересует именно настройка редиски. Я не смог нагуглить что-то полезно-понятное по работе ВП редиса (ну кроме "включайте редис - будет вам щастя :) ")

Comment: А там и нет никаких настроек в redis. Просто работает из коробки)

Comment: W3TC был популярен, да. Нло как-то потом все перешли на Redis для объектов + Rocket для страниц, например. Говорили, что Rocket быстрее. А я относительно недавно ушел на FlyingPress - это вообще чемпион по страничному кешированию.

Comment: Но главное в кешировании страниц - даже не выбор плагина, а выдача кеша напрямую из nginx/apache без старта плагина кеширования. Я об этом не раз писал.

Comment: @KAGGDesign,  насчёт "нет настроек" -редиска  это серьёзная вещь. По хорошему под каждый сайт нужно свою базу создавать, но мало кто об этом задумывается. И у неё, естественно,  [есть конфиг с настройками](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/). А насчёт выдачи кеша напрямую - это касается постраничного кеширования. Для кеша объектов и плаг обязателен и север/система кеширования нужна. Ну и если тебе интересно - [вот скрин](https://i.imgur.com/TMnnirW.jpeg) с W3TC  всего одной страницы настройки (объектов). В админ-меню можешь увидеть, что прибл. такие же настройки по каждому виду кеша

Comment: 1. Я знаю про настройки W3TC, работал с ним.
2. Не надо базу под сайт создавать. Никаких настрокек не надо. Всё, что надо, чтобы держать неколько сайтов на одном сервере, добавить в каждый wp-config.php `define( 'WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', __DIR__ );` Впрочем, эта константа для Redis Cache плагина, но у W3TC  должна быть аналогичная.